# Is there an elementary way to see that there is only one complex manifold structure on $R^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Is there an elementary way to see that there is only one complex manifold structure on $\mathbb{R}^2$? (Up to biholomorphism, naturally.)

Elementary in the sense of not appealing to the uniformization theorem.

Comment: You can't, because there's not - there are two! And this is almost precisely equivalent  to the uniformization theorem.

Comment: This is precisely the example I gave for this MO question: [Examples of common false beliefs](http://mathoverflow.net/a/212483/21564).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two, not one. The open unit disc is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$, and it's not biholomorphic to $\Bbb C$, so it's a distinct complex structure.

You will have trouble proving this in an easy way. Let me restate the uniformization theorem:

Every simply connected complex surface is biholomorphic to the plane, sphere, or open unit disc.

But I can tell you all of the simply connected surfaces without boundary: there's $S^2$ and $\Bbb R^2$ and that's it! So we can rephrase the uniformization theorem as follows:

Every two complex structures on $S^2$ are biholomorphic. Every complex structure on $\Bbb R^2$ is biholomorphic to either the complex plane or open unit disc.

So the uniformization theorem does not say much more than what you're asking for; if someone asked me for a proof I would tell them to read the uniformization theorem. (You can't just use Riemann mapping - it's not obvious that a complex manifold homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$ has a holomorphic embedding into $\Bbb C$.)

Comment: What if I insisted that this complex structure was invariant under of $R^2$ by translation? I am trying (for the purpose of my own understanding) to conclude that given a complex torus, the complex structure on the universal cover induced by lifting holomorphic patches must be the standard one. And for the hyperbolic surfaces I guess that the deck transformation group of would force more structure as well.

Comment: @AreaMan: This comes down to the fact that we know the group of conformal transformations of the unit disc, and $\Bbb Z^2$ is not a discrete subgroup of that. See [these](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~asalehig/Lecture2David.pdf) notes for a proof.